# Cannot convert value of type '(() throws -> Void?) -> ()' to expected argument type '((Void) throws -> Void)?'

Tags: swift, rx-swift, throws

I have a reactive method who should return `((Void) throws -> Void)?` to be used into `.on(onNext: myUIComponent.rx.function)` but no matters what I do I never get what is expected.

I was tries

`func name() throws -> Void?`

`func name(xpto: ((Void) throws -> Void?) = nil)`

Someone have some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh, nothing is necessary, just create a `func name()` without return like

```
extension Reactive where Base: ReactiveUIComponent {
    func name() {
        ...
    }
}

button.rx.tap
    .do(onNext: reactiveUIComponent.rx.name)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
func name(xpto: ((Void) throws -> Void)? = nil)
```

(`?` outside of the parenthesis.) That makes the whole closure optional, rather than an optional that returns a void optional, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah @Duncan C, the "solution" was posted above.